# My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system update takes too long

Tags: apt, update-manager

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system update takes too long (too much time).

Finally a message comes up stating that there is a problem with Internet connection and updating has failed.

When I examined the Terminal output, the following links has been 404 (link not found, timeout) errors.

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net..... 

precise/main Sources    

precise/main amd64 Packages

precise/main i386 Packages

/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  

/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  

/crebs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

How can I remove those links?

Is there any other solution?

*Please help me. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2):

I would not remove them, I am pretty sure these are the ppas that contain the security and bug updates for your system ( I'm still new to this so I may be mistaken ). If you want to temporarily disable them you can open the software & updates section of system settings and attempt to disable them from there. If that does not do it you could download and install the Synaptic Package handler `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and search for those packages and disable them that way.

I want to state once more that I think this is not the way to go. i would consider waiting a bit and trying again later in case it is just a connection issue. If you are trying to update a specific program and this error is preventing you from doing that you can ask `apt-get` to update individual programs just read the man page by typing `man apt-get` into the terminal.

Sorry I could not be of more help, i am new to Linux myself and am doing my best to get involved. Please let us know what you end up doing to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has resolved after I changed the server mirror.

I searched and selected best server with

`SOFTWARE & UPDATES` > `UBUNTU SOFTWARE` > `DOWNLOAD` > `OTHER` > `SELECT BEST SERVER.`